# Extjs 3.4 get Key value on comboBox key events

Tags: javascript, extjs, key-events

I want to identify which key is pressed on keyUp keyDown or other event on combo box. I have set `enableKeyEvents: true,` in my config file and added event handler.

```
this.a.on('keyup', this.onAKeyPress, this);
```

and function

```
onAKeyPress: function(e){
        console.log(e.getKey());
    },
```

And i get error, that e.getKey() is not a function in firebug. But in extJS documentation is said http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.EventObject that e has function getKey(), so where the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyup` event has 2 options: the element itself and an event object, which is 2nd argument.

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-keyup

So on your case:

```
onAKeyPress: function(combo, event) {
    console.log(event.getKey());
},
```

Comment: oh, shame on me, i have taken only one parameter instead of two. Thanks man. Saved my time :)